# Conky runs the same curl request multiple times per interval

Tags: bash, shell, curl, conky

The API responds with an XML file containing everything. I want some of the data in that XML to appear in parts of my conky

I have a bash script to fetch and parse the data. It looks like

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -z $1 ]; then
        echo "missing arguments"
        exit 0;
fi
curl -s http://example.com/api.php | xmllint --xpath "//${1}/text()" -
```

and in .conkyrc I have

```
${color slate grey}Number of cats: ${color }
${execi 3600 myscript.sh cats}

${color slate grey}Color of the day: ${color }
${execi 3600 myscript.sh color}

${color slate grey}Some other stuff: ${color }
${execi 3600 myscript.sh stuff}
```

This works *fine*, but I'm making 3 requests to the API every interval even though all the data I need is passed the first time.

The obvious solution is change the bash script to save the API response to a temp file with a timestamp on it. Wherever the script is run, first check the temp file's timestamp to see if it's out of date (or doesn't exist). If so, delete it and make a new curl request. If not, swap the curl statement with a

```
cat tempfile.xml | xmllint
```

But I don't like leave temp files all over the place or worrying about potential race conditions. Is there a way to return all the data I need from my script and give it to conky to store as conky variables and then print them in the right location? Or more broadly, how should I go about improving this?

Comment: Do `${color slate grey}` markers work correctly if the script output contains them? Because if they do then you could just move all of that code to the shell script and then save the curl output to a variable and `echo` that to `xmllint` as necessary. (Though even running `xmllint` three times would be unnecessary since you could write a single xsl transform to do the whole thing at once.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your script to use a cache:

```
#!/bin/sh

CACHE_FILE=/var/cache/api.data

check_missing_arg() {
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        echo "missing arguments"
        exit 0
    fi
}

if [ "$1" = --use-cache ] && [ -f "$CACHE_FILE" ]; then
    shift
    check_missing_arg "$@"
    xmllint --xpath "//${1}/text()" "$CACHE_FILE"
elif [ "$1" = --store-cache ]; then
    shift
    check_missing_arg "$@"
    curl -s http://example.com/api.php > "$CACHE_FILE"
    xmllint --xpath "//${1}/text()" "$CACHE_FILE"
else
    check_missing_arg "$@"
    curl -s http://example.com/api.php | xmllint --xpath "//${1}/text()" -
fi
```

And in your `.conkyrc`:

```
${color slate grey}Number of cats: ${color }
${execi 3600 myscript.sh --store-cache cats}

${color slate grey}Color of the day: ${color }
${execi 3600 myscript.sh --use-cache color}

${color slate grey}Some other stuff: ${color }
${execi 3600 myscript.sh --use-cache stuff}
```

- It may be nice to write the cache on a `tmpfs`. Some distros have `/dev/shm` mounted by default as `tmpfs`.

Comment: Ha, just have the first instance include an argument to clear the previous cache. What a simple idea, I can't believe I didn't think of it. Thanks! And I have /tmp mounted as tmpfs, so I was going to use that.